# heroku run rake db:migrate doesn't work

Tags: heroku, rake, migrate

After hours and hours of research, can someone help me for this problem:

When I put the command heroku run rake db:migrate, I've got this issue:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Your version of git is 1.9.4.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1875 rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Pinteresting
/app/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My github: github.com/Nolwen38/pinteresting
Context: I just registered to aws.amazon and put my amazon's informations on githash settings.
I have windows 7 32bit
Thanks for your help!
BR
Nolwen

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with your production.rb file

Comment: It seems like there is a problem on production.rb, but I don't understand what does it mean: /production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

I made some changes in this file to create aws.amazon database. Maybe the problem comes from here...

Thanks
Nolwen

Comment: Its the line above - it doesn't like the line that has Pinteresting in it. Maybe post that file and the application.rb file

Answer (score 0):

Production.rb

```
Pinteresting::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Required for Heroku
  # Note to set this to your actual host
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'omr-pinteresting.com' }

  # Sets Paperclip to upload images to Amazon S3
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
end
```

Application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module HelloWorld
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Required for Heroku
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end
```

BR